# R duplicate an environment object and remove its references to other libraries

Tags: r, ggplot2, environment

**Problem Overview:** I am trying to extract only the relevant code I need from an R package called [ggpattern](https://github.com/coolbutuseless/ggpattern) but I am running into an issue with two environment objects in the library that I cannot figure out how to duplicate outside of the package.

**Background:** I cannot just load the whole package ggpattern because my organization's R Studio Server Pro will not allow me to install it because of its dependencies on packages gridpattern and magik (specifically magik is not compatible with our server set-up). Therefore, I only want to copy the necessary code from ggpattern for the specific task I need which is to create a bar graph with striped bars.

I received permission from the package's maintainer to do this.  He has also assured me that ggpattern is a pure R package and that magik is not required to do the task I need.

Here is the essential ggpattern code I want to run to generate a bar graph with a striped bar:

```
ggplot(wr, aes(x = A, y = P, fill = interaction(C, W), pattern = W.P)) +
geom_bar_pattern(stat = "identity", 
                 position = "dodge",
                 color = "black",
                 pattern_angle = 45,
                 pattern_density = 0.5,
                 pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.41,
                 pattern_fill = "white",
                 pattern_color = "white") +
scale_pattern_manual(values = c("GP" = "none",
                                "WII" = "stripe",
                                "SLM" = "none"),
                     labels = c("GP","WII","SLM"))
```

I need the functions geom_bar_pattern() and scale_pattern_manual() from ggpattern.

**Steps Taken So Far:**

I traced geom_bar_pattern() and scale_pattern_manual() to the lowest level I could in ggpattern and its dependencies and put those functions into a separate script (it a long script so I did not include it in this post).

The issue that remains is that the functions I pasted into the new script also require two environment objects named GeomBarPattern and GeomRectPattern.  I cannot figure out how to duplicate these and make them independent from ggpattern, and its dependency packages like gridpattern and magik.

I have tried saving these two environments as new objects and uploading them to R Studio Server Pro but it does not work because it seems they just refer back to ggpattern (and maybe gridpattern too).  I saved the environments as .RData files on my local machine which can use ggpattern:

```
GeomBarPattern <- ggpattern::GeomBarPattern
save(GeomBarPattern, file = "./Prototype/GeomBarPattern.RData")
GeomRectPattern <- ggpattern::GeomRectPattern
save(GeomRectPattern, file = "./Prototype/GeomRectPattern.RData")
```

When I uploaded those files to R Studio Server Pro and loaded them this is the error message I get:

```
> load("GeomBarPattern.RData")
Warning: namespace ‘ggpattern’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘GeomBarPattern’
> load("GeomRectPattern.RData")
Warning: namespace ‘ggpattern’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘GeomRectPattern’
```

How do I go about duplicating the essential contents I need from GeomBarPattern and GeomGridPattern and making those independent from ggpattern, gridpattern, and magik?

Comment: I would go a different route: remove the offending dependencies from the package and build it. I suspect you can just search the github repository for the package names. Alternatively, create `GeomBarPattern` yourself instead of trying to copy it: https://github.com/coolbutuseless/ggpattern/blob/3c661b641e2ee0a328e54ff52c550f2018117460/R/geom-bar.R#L54 Of course, you also need the super classes.

Comment: The package maintainer removed {magik} as a required dependency today so I tried re-installing {gridpattern} and {ggpattern} again but what I'm finding is I still need to install at least a CRAN package called {sf} which is a hard requirement for what I'm trying to do.  To remove {sf} as a dependency the main packages I need would require a significant re-write which isn't feasible. I can't install {sf} on R Studio Server Pro for some reason.  I started a R Community thread on the issue: https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-install-ggpattern-and-its-dependencies-on-r-studio-server-pro/119777

Comment: Well, are the [system requirements](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html) installed on the server? I guess they are not. (Your issue is with CRAN packages. Your server admins are lazy or don't know what they are talking about.)